# how to solve this: vapor receive response property output format is changed?

Tags: vapor

I want use a content struct to decode the response, but some case the output property is:

```json
"output": [
    {
        "file": "aaa.jpg"
    }
],
```

and some case output property is:

```json
"output": "aaa.jpg"
```

how can I do for this?

```swift
struct ReplicateModelData: Codable {
  let output: String?
}

try response.content.decode(ReplicateModelData.self)
```

output type is changed, and cannot decode success everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by:

1. convert to json string from response.body
2. convert to dict
3. judge the dict, and make a struct object by manual.